# How to get and use values from a dict of a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key

I have a dictionary of a list of tuples:

```
adict = {'alpha': [('0', 'beta'), ('1', 'beta')], 
         'beta': [('0', 'alpha'), ('1', 'alpha')]}
```

and a list of values:

```
alist = ['alpha', '0', '1', '0']
blist = ['beta', '0', '1', '0', 'x']
```

I want to be able to use the first index as a key to search through the dictionary and then using the numbers in the list to search through the tuples and append matched tuples (with the first element of the tuple) with the value into a final list. I don't know if I'm being clear enough but in the end I want the final list to be

```
final_list = [ ['alpha', ('0', 'beta'), ('1', 'beta'), ('0', 'beta')],
               ['beta', ('0', 'alpha'), ('1', 'alpha'), ('0', 'alpha'), ('x': None)] ]
```

Its sort of a multi-level search. How would I approach this?

Comment: Could you use an example where the strings aren't equal right through the list?

Answer (score 2):

Create a temporary dict first, in which the values of `adict` are dictionary itself. And then use a list comprehension to get the desired list.

```
>>> temp_adict = {k:dict(v) for k, v in adict.items()}
>>> [ lis[:1] + [(x, temp_adict[lis[0]].get(x)) for x in lis[1:]]
                                                       for lis in [alist, blist]]
[['alpha', ('0', 'beta'), ('1', 'beta'), ('0', 'beta')],
['beta', ('0', 'alpha'), ('1', 'alpha'), ('0', 'alpha'), ('x', None)]]
```

Comment: Oops, I misread the question. Yours is a much better implementation!

Comment: Splendid! I got it. So lets say if I were to add a random string 'x', into blist so blist = ['beta', '0', '1', '0', 'x']. How would I catch it from crashing?

Comment: @user2559679 You can add an `if` condition inside the list comprehension to handle that: `[(x, temp_adict[lis[0]][x]) for x in lis[1:] if x in temp_adict[lis[0]]]`. If you want to use a dummy value for missing keys instead of filtering them, use `dict.get`.

Comment: I would much prefer to use a a dummy value for missing keys rather than filtering. How would I use `dict.get()` to approach this? `dict.get(x) if not in temp_adict[lis[0]]`?

Answer (score 0):

this ugliness does the thing in one line.... beware, it's ugly!

```
solution = [[alist[0]] + [(key, adict[alist[0]][index][1]) for key in alist[1:] for index in xrange(len(adict[alist[0]])) if adict[alist[0]][index][0] == key]] + [[blist[0]] + [(key, adict[blist[0]][index][1]) for key in blist[1:] for index in xrange(len(adict[alist[0]])) if adict[alist[0]][index][0] == key]]
```

it's also not very DRY, just does the job in 1 line, if that matters for whatever reason